# Not using await when you don't care about the result

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I'm using the stack exchange redis library on IIS. This is a very general question which I haven't found an answer to.

If I am recording analytics where I don't care about the response to the redis call, can I do an async say string increment and not await it ever and trust that it will finish and not be cancelled if my request completes\terminates etc?

The goal being to reduce the amount of time the client is waiting for the response to be rendered.

Comment: _" and trust that it will finish"_ - nope. But you don't care about the result, so you don't care if it finishes, right?

Comment: just run the task in a background worker of some kind. (in asp.net core, "hosted service" ought to be the easiest solution)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann in this case, there is a *much* simpler way to achieve this aim...

Comment: true. but, for the use case "making sure it finishes", one _has_ to wait for the result in _some_ way.

Comment: What I really meant was that if these calls finish 99% of the time I dont care if a few get missed, the question was more about will my webserver or AWS lambda somehow cancel them once the request is processed or will they run in the background and I can assume they will do their job most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

In the SE-Redis library, there is a feature specifically for this: "fire and forget". Almost every operation accepts an optional `CommandFlags` parameter: specify `CommandFlags.FireAndForget` (using "or" (`|`) to combine if you're already passing another flag) - your command will be sent but the local method will return immediately. You shouldn't really look at it, but the method will immediately return the default value for whatever the declared type is. Finally, it may be easier to use the *non-async* API, just so the compiler doesn't prompt you to `await` it unnecessarily (although again: it won't actually be truly async in this case).

Comment: In your experience, when this happens on a webserver or lambda context, these don't get aborted when the request finishes if they happen to still be in the que\pending in some way?